# Launch application in background

Tags: java, service, process

I have a common question, how it is possible to launch a Third-Party application in Java, without to open it in the desktop (start the application as process?). I stuck at this point, so is there a way to open an application in an "hidden" mode.

OS: Windows Server 2008

Comment: what is your operating system ?

Comment: I am using Windows (Server 2008)

Comment: You can take a look at [this post on ServerFault][1] related to the same point.


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

Comment: I am developing a webservice, out of this, a application must be start on the server: so I don't can use a batch file i think

Comment: Is it a jar file or exe?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan it is an exe

Answer (score 1):

As Ronald said, you can create a **batch** file to start the third party application in the background. Add the batch file to the windows services **startup** in **automatic** mode. This is the easiest way you can make it run at startup in the background